# Execute task for any possible hotkey combinations following winkey

Tags: autohotkey

I want any possible key sequence started with LWin to execute a particular task, for example:

```
LWin & a::
;Execute the task
```

or:

```
LWin & b::
;Execute the task
```

And so on...

For all keyboard keys of course, writing this would be impossible, so I thought of something like this:

```
LWin & *::     ; * = KEY
KEY = %A_ThisHotkey%    ; KEY is now = LWin & a (for example)
KEY := RegExReplace(Clipboard,"i)^lwIN & ")    ; KEY is now = a
; The task that needs to be executed:
Send {LWin UP}
Send {%KEY% DOWN}
KeyWait %KEY%
Send {%KEY% up}
return
```

But the problem is, the wildcard can't be used like that. How to accomplish this?

Comment: Would you like it to be specific to a particular active window?  Do you need to be able to cancel the bindings (e.g., pressing Esc)?

Comment: @JoeCoder Yes I use #IfWinActive on the actual code, and I don't think I need to cancel the bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*LWin::
    Input, key, L1
    if (ErrorLevel = "NewInput")
        Send, {LWin}      ; LWin was pressed alone: pass-thru
    else if (IsLabel(key))
        Goto, % key
    else
        Send, % "#" key   ; pass-thru
return
*LWin UP::Input           ; stop listening for secondary key

; Tasks defined here
s:
    MsgBox, "s" task launched!
return
p:
    MsgBox, "p" task launched!
return
```

Comment: It took me a long while to fully understand it xD but now I understand, and it works perfect, thanks a lot :D